# SSRS report viewer loading slow

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I'm trying to integrate some of our SSRS reports into our web application. I'm having a problem where the first time the report is rendered is super slow (15-20 seconds). Subsequent reports are almost instant for a few minutes. If I come back 5-10 minute later and try to run a report, it's super slow again.

I've tried messing around in the AppPool for the report server (changing the idle time out and how often the worker process recycles). Nothing seems to help.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is a better fit here or on serverfault. I know a lot of us devs deal with server perf issues, but that doesn't necessarily mean we know what we're doing :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue with SSRS.  You can trigger the automatic reset of the Application Domain by a PowerShell script as [this blog](http://www.pawlowski.cz/2011/07/solving-issue-long-starting-report-ssrs-2008/) explains

Comment: I had read through that blog previously, but as far as I can tell if my problem was what is described in the blog, then I would only have a slow load every 720 minutes. I'm having one every 5 or so. Further, If I run a report on my machine and have someone else run the same report on their machine immediately after, both reports are slow. It seems to be on a per user basis that it's being reset.